# Angular 2 validator not working as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-formbuilder, angular-validation

I got this validator:

```
export const PasswordsEqualValidator = (): ValidatorFn => {

  return (group: FormGroup): Observable<{[key: string]: boolean}> => {

    const passwordCtrl: FormControl = <FormControl>group.controls.password;
    const passwordAgainCtrl: FormControl = <FormControl>group.controls.passwordAgain;

    const valid = passwordCtrl.value.password === passwordAgainCtrl.value.passwordAgain;

    return Observable.of(valid ? null : {
      passwordsEqual: true
    });
  };
};
```

Which is used in this form:

```
  public signupForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    email: ['', Validators.required],
    passwords: this.fb.group({
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      passwordAgain: ['', Validators.required]
    }, {validator: CustomValidators.passwordsEqual()})
  });
```

Part of the template which uses it:

```
<div formGroupName="passwords">
  <div class="form-control" [ngClass]="{error: !signupForm.get('passwords').valid}">
    <label class="label" for="password">Password</label>
    <input class="input" id="password" formControlName="password" type="password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-control" [ngClass]="{error: !signupForm.get('passwords').valid}">
    <label class="label" for="password-again">Password again</label>
    <input class="input" id="password-again" formControlName="passwordAgain" type="password">
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that even when the passwords match, it still shows the error. I've looked at a number of different similar questions but most of em are a bit cluttered and outdated so I wanted to write a cleaner solution.

I'm guessing there's just a small adjustment needed but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this, because you need compare 2 value and the validator is not async validator, you could return only boolean instead of Observable

```
export const PasswordsEqualValidator = (): ValidatorFn => {

  return (group: FormGroup): boolean => {

    const passwordCtrl: FormControl = <FormControl>group.controls.password;
    const passwordAgainCtrl: FormControl = <FormControl>group.controls.passwordAgain;

    const valid = passwordCtrl.value === passwordAgainCtrl.value;

    return valid ? null : {
      passwordsEqual: true
    };
  };
};
```

btw, using this method for best practice:

```
export const PasswordsEqualValidator = (): ValidatorFn => {

  return (group: FormGroup): boolean => {

    const passwordCtrl: FormControl = group.get('password');
    const passwordAgainCtrl: FormControl = group.get('passwordAgain');

    const valid = passwordCtrl.value === passwordAgainCtrl.value;

    return valid ? null : {
      passwordsEqual: true
    };
  };
};
```

demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/9PzGSIuBhvNz0fpJxTlS?p=preview

Comment: Good catch, but it's also saying "Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.".. Not sure when that started to happen hmm..

Comment: sorry, I do not read careful your question, please take a look my updated answer

Comment: This is so weird.. I'm using the same exact code as in the plunkr but the error still throws, doesn't make any sense...

Comment: Oh my lord those damn brackets when using more than one validator.. they should really throw an error for that... now it's working :) Thank you!